# To identify numbers alongside words and performing some mathematical operation

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

I am creating a chatbot and I need to know how to perform some mathematical operation (let's say adding) when I give a raw input 'Add 12 and 13'. How can I make my program print 25?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as "Too Broad" because it seems to be asking how to write a whole program. It covers parsing input text, mapping that to function calls, printing output, and the implied error handling and natural language interpretation required for a chat bot are huge fields on their own. Please make an attempt at writing this program yourself and come back with a more specific question when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that **regular expressions** and **anonymous functions** will help you.

Defining your lexic and semantic, you ought capture all the strings; and verify if the text of the chat is matching with the operation that you want to proccess:

```
>> import re
>> input = "add 15 and 12 today"
>> regex = r'(add)\s+(\d+)\s+(and)\s+(\d+)'
>> extracted_words = re.findall(regex, input)
```

Note that the output for `extracted_words` will be something like this:

```
[('add', '15', 'and', '12')]
```

If it match, you could do something like this:

```
if re.match(regex, input) is not None:
    extracted_words = re.findall(regex, input)

    # Function sum
    # You can define whether your functions or use some defined everywhere 
    sum = lambda extracted_words: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda num: int(num), filter(lambda word: word.isdigit(), extracted_words)))

    total_sum = sum(extracted_words[0])

    ...

    [use your total_sum]
```

Comment: it shows an error that the name content is not defined in in the if statement

Comment: sorry. I didn't add. The content variable is actually your content (your chatbot string input). I'll fix it, thanks for inform.

Comment: I've modified the code, adding the `input` variable instead of `content` variable. You can try again @AuroniBhattacharya

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by split() and type conversion like this

```
str=input() #add 12 and 32
str=str.split()
operator=str[0]
first=int(str[1])
second=int(str[3])

if operator=='add':
    print(first+second)

if operator=='substract': #for substract you will use 'from' rather than 'and'
    print(second-first)

if operator=='multiply':
    print(first*second)

if operator=='divide': #for divide you will use 'by' rather than 'and'
    print(first/second)
```

you will get the result and add what ever condition you want in 'if condition'